# SQLite Insert trigger how to delete old records in the table based on two values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm using SQLite Android, and I have a table that contains two columns id and feedId, I want to delete old items in the same feedId after insert new records if count > 10
This is the table

```
id  feedId
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  1
12  2
13  2
14  2
15  2
16  2
17  2
18  2
19  2
20  2
21  2
22  2
```

I have 11 records in the feedId 1 and 11 records in the feedId 2 so I want to delete 1 record from feedId 1 and 1 record from feedId 2

Tried this query

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS articles_limiter AFTER INSERT ON articles BEGIN DELETE FROM articles WHERE feedId in (SELECT feedId FROM (SELECT feedId,count(*) as cnt FROM articles GROUP BY feedId HAVING cnt > 10)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT -1 OFFSET 10; end;
```

But it's work only if there is one feedId that have count > 10, but it will not work if there is two or more feedId that have count > 10

Comment: Your question says "delete" but your sample code is `select`, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 10 rows per `feedId`, use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by feedId order by id desc) as seqnum
      from articles a
     ) a
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Comment: It's will get only first 10 items per feedId but I want to delete all items and keep only last 10 items per feedId, My query just for test I want DELETE not SELECT

Comment: So my query will be like this
```
"CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS articles_limiter AFTER INSERT ON articles BEGIN DELETE FROM articles WHERE feedId in (SELECT feedId FROM (SELECT feedId,count(*) as ali FROM articles GROUP BY feedId HAVING ali > 10)) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT -1 OFFSET 10; end;"```

Comment: Please note that I'm using android sqlite

Comment: @MohamedHamdan . . . SQLite has supported window functions since version 3.28.0, released in early 2019.